# Get Newest Record from CloudKit Database

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery

I'm new to CloudKit (and haven't used `NSPredicate` much) and am looking to do something which, I'd imagine, is quite basic. I'd like to retrieve the data record with the newest `creationDate`.

Right now I'm just pulling all the records and scooping up the last one, but there's got to be a more elegant way. Here's my current approach:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "NewsItem", predicate: predicate)

CKContainer(identifier: "…").publicCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: CKRecordZone.default().zoneID) { result, error in
    let sortedRecords = result.sorted {
        guard let date1 = $0.value(forKey: "creationDate") as? Date,
              let date2 = $1.value(forKey: "creationDate") as? Date else {
            return false
        }
        return date1 < date2
    }

    let item = NewsItem(from: sortedRecords[0])
    …
}
```

I've used `NSPredicate` to get a subset of results before, but never max/min style results. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a step in the right direction:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "NewsItem", predicate: predicate)
query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

CKContainer(identifier: "…").publicCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: CKRecordZone.default().zoneID) { result, error in
    let item = NewsItem(from: result.last)
    …
}
```

Though I'm still curious if there's a way to simply query by max creationDate…